# how to pass a parameter to $.window function in jquery.window.js

Tags: ruby

- I am doing rails project.
- I had requirement when click on link the render page should be open in     -new window.

  - For that i am using jquery window.js
- This is code in that function to show the render page.
  content:  -`('<%=escape_javascript(render"business_settings/wgu_settings_page") %>')`
  but i am unable to pass locals along with render.

  can anybody solve this

Comment: Can you give the reason why you can't pass locals with just `render("business_settings/wgu_settings_page", locals: { a: 'b'}")` ?

Comment: use jquery.window.js and add what are the partial u want to add and test it whether it is going or not.i tried so many ways it is not working.

Comment: Can you give a little more info on how you are calling the window function along with the arguments ?